# Workflow and Page Content Types

Tags: workflow, content-type

In 2007 I am trying to understand the use of workflows added to page based content types that will eventually live in a page library.

If I add a workflow to such a content type then use that content type the workflows aren't available. If I follow the same process for document based content types and add these to a document library the workflows work fine.

Comment: stupid question....did you try to publish the workflow first?

Comment: The workflow is created/added from within the CT settings. I didnt know it could be published?

Answer (score 1):

Check if "Require content approval for submitted items" enabled on "Pages" document library. This option can be found in "Versioning settings" of document library settings...